# sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true isn't working in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm doing a custom sheet extension to mimic the Apple's Plan App bottom sheet.

In portrait it's perfect but in landscape it is in full screen despite having set the `sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true`.

Here is the chunk of code

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct HomeView: View {

    @State private var showControls = true
    
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .bottomSheet(
                presentationDetents: [.height(70), .medium, .large],
                isPresented: $showControls,
                sheetCornerRadius: 40,
                isTransparent: true
            ) {
                VStack {
                    SearchFieldView()
                        .padding()
                        .padding(.top, 35)
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        SheetContent()
                    }
                }
                .background(content: {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                })
            } onDismiss: {

            }
    }

}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
//          .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeRight)
    }
}

extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func SheetContent() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            HStack(spacing: 12) {
                Text("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func bottomSheet<Content: View>(
        presentationDetents: Set<PresentationDetent>,
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        dragIndicator: Visibility = .visible,
        sheetCornerRadius: CGFloat?,
        largestUndimmedIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier = .large,
        prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight: Bool = true,
        widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached: Bool = true,
        isTransparent: Bool = false,
        interactiveDisabled: Bool = true,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        onDismiss: @escaping () -> ()
    ) -> some View {
        self.sheet(
            isPresented: isPresented
        ) {
            onDismiss()
        } content: {
            content()
                .presentationDetents(presentationDetents)
                .presentationDragIndicator(dragIndicator)
                .interactiveDismissDisabled(interactiveDisabled)
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                .onAppear {
                    func applyPreferences() {
                        guard let windows = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
                        
                        if
                            let controller = windows.windows.first?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController,
                            let sheet = controller.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController
                        {
                            
                            print("Apply bottom sheet preferences")
                            controller.presentingViewController?.view.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
                            controller.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                            
                            if isTransparent {
                                controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
                            }
                            
                            sheet.preferredCornerRadius = sheetCornerRadius
                            sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium // Map not reactive when sheet fullscreen
                            sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
                            sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
                            sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
                        } else {
                            print("Cannot apply bottom sheet preferences")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    // Custom code for bottom sheet
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        applyPreferences()
                    }
                    
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
//                      applyPreferences()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
}
```

First thing, I want the bottom sheet to act like the native sheet in landscape mode (not fullscreen and able to close it.

Second thing, when I toggle between orientations then I go back to portrait and the cornerRadius just reset to default... I have to do an interval to fix it... Any help on that too?